# The second row of tags on the user card is obscured in the mobile chat

Tags: bug, design, chat, user-card

The second row of tags on the [user card](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46689392#46689392) is obscured in the mobile chat:

> [image]

You need to join the chat. Transcript view isn't affected, but tags overlaps each other:

> [image]